# Python Object has no attribute error

Tags: python, attributes

```
class EmptyMap():
    """
    EmptyMap has no slots
    """
    __slots__ = ()

class NonEmptyMap():
    """
    Has slots of left, key, value, and right. 
    """
    __slots__ = ('left', 'key', 'value', 'right')

def mkEmptyMap():
    """
    Is a function that takes no arguments and returns an instance of EmptyMap
    """
    return EmptyMap()

def mkNonEmptyMap(left, key, value, right):
    """
    Is a function that takes a map, a key, a value, and another map,
    and returns an instance of NonEmptyMap. This function merely initializes the slots;
    it is possible to use this function to create trees that are not binary search trees.
    """
    nonEmptyMap = NonEmptyMap()
    nonEmptyMap.left = left
    nonEmptyMap.key = key
    nonEmptyMap.value = value
    nonEmptyMap.right = right
    return nonEmptyMap

def mapInsert(key, value, node):
    """
    Is a function that takes a key, a value, and a map, and returns an instance
    of NonEmptyMap. Further, the map that is returned is a binary search tree based
    on the keys. The function inserts the key-value pair into the correct position in the
    map. The map returned need not be balanced. Before coding, review the binary
    search tree deﬁnition and the structurally recursive design pattern, and determine
    what the function should look like for maps. If the key already exists, the new value
    should replace the old value.
    """
    if isinstance(node, EmptyMap):
        return mkNonEmptyMap(mkEmptyMap(), key, value, mkEmptyMap())
    else:
        if key > node.key:
            node.right = mapInsert(key, value, node.right)
            return node.right
        elif key < node.key:
            node.left = mapInsert(key, value, node.left)
            return node.left
        elif key == node.key:
            node.value = value
            return mapInsert(key, value, node)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Bad Tree Map")

def mapToString(node):
    """
    Is a function that takes a map, and returns a string that represents the
    map. Before coding, review the structurally recursive design pattern, and determine
    how to adapt it for maps. An EmptyMap is represented as ’ ’. For an instance of
    NonEmptyMap, the left sub-tree appears on the left, and the right sub-tree appears
    on the right.
    """
    if isinstance(node, EmptyMap):
        return '_'
    elif isinstance(node, NonEmptyMap):
       return '(' + mapToString(node.left) + ',' + str(node.key) + '->'  + str(node.value) + ',' + mapToString(node.right)+ ')'
    else:
       raise TypeError("Not a Binary Tree")

def mapSearch(key, node):
    """
    Is a function that takes a key and a map, and returns the value associated
    with the key or None if the key is not there. Before coding, review the binary search
    tree deﬁnition and the structurally recursive design pattern, and determine how it
    should look for maps.
    """
    if isinstance(node, EmptyMap):
       return 'None'
    elif isinstance(node, NonEmptyMap):
       if key == node.key:
          return str(node.value)
       elif key < node.key:
          return mapSearch(key, node.left)
       elif key > node.key:
          return mapSearch(key, node.right)
    else:
       raise TypeError("Not a Binary Tree")

def main():
    smallMap = mapInsert(\
        'one',\
        1,\
        mapInsert(\
            'two',\
            2,\
            mapInsert(\
                'three',\
                3,\
                mkEmptyMap())))

    print(smallMap.key)
    print(smallMap.left.key)
    print(smallMap.right.key)

main()
```

When I run the program, I got a syntax which I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I am pretty sure the emptymap has an object which is in mkNonEmptyMap function. This is my homework problem.

A map is a data structure that associates values with keys. One can search for a particular key to ﬁnd its associated value. For example, the value 3 could be associated with the key ’three’.

```
one
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/USER/Desktop/test.py", line 113, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/USER/Desktop/test.py", line 110, in main
    print(smallMap.left.key)
AttributeError: 'EmptyMap' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil What is your point? Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you indent it correctly, so it's easier for us to help you? Or it's correctly indented now?

Comment: Obviously the problem is that `smallMap.left` is an `EmptyMap`. Which you can see very easily by printing out `smallMap.left` or `mapToString(smallMap)`. So, the first question is: what did you _expect_ `smallMap.left` to be? What in your code should be causing that to be true? Where is it going wrong? Until you can answer that, you aren't even asking a useful question, much less solving it.

Comment: Also, when you have a complex 10-line expression that isn't doing the right thing, it helps to break it down into steps and bind the intermediate results to variables. Do `empty = mkEmptyMap()`, then `three = mapInsert('three', 3, empty)`, then `two = mapInsert('two', 2, three)`, then `one = mapInsert('one', 1, two)` and see where things go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at what's in `smallMap`, its `left` and `right` are both `EmptyMap`s. So of course `smallMap.left.key` isn't going to work—`EmptyMap`s don't have `key`s.

So, why is it wrong? Well, let's break that monster expression down into steps and see where it goes wrong:

```
>>> empty = mkEmptyMap()
>>> mapToString(empty)
'_'
>>> three = mapInsert('three', 3, mkEmptyMap())
>>> mapToString(three)
'(_,three->3,_)'
>>> two = mapInsert('two', 2, three)
>>> mapToString(two)
(_,two->2,_)
```

There's a problem. The `two` object has no left or right. What about `three`?

```
>>> mapToString(three)
(_,three->3,(_,two->2,_))
```

OK, so we do have a valid balanced tree—but it's not in the `two` object returned by `mapInsert`, it's in the `three` object that you passed in to `mapInsert` (which your original program isn't even keeping a reference to).

So, why is that happening? Is that valid? It depends on your design. If you want to mutate your arguments like this, it's perfectly reasonable to do so (although I suspect it's not what your teacher actually wanted—anyone who's trying to force you to write ML in Python like this probably wants you to use non-mutating algorithms…). But then you need to always return the root node. Your function is clearly trying to return the newly-created node whether it's the root or not. So, just fix that:

```
    if key > node.key:
        node.right = mapInsert(key, value, node.right)
        return node # not node.right
```

And likewise for the other two cases. (I'm not sure why you were trying to call yourself recursively in the `==` case in the first place.)

If you do that, the code no longer has an error.

It doesn't seem to be actually balancing the tree correctly, but that's the next problem for you to solve.

Comment: wow That seems to fix my problem! Thank you so much. I get it now. Thanks for the description, I understand better now than before.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by, "it doesn't seem to balance the tree correctly"? In addition to that, what the output suppose to be?

Comment: @Singh2013: For example, try inserting `"four"` and `"five"` after the first three; you will end up with 3 nodes on the left subtree and 1 on the right. Which is fine for this exercise, because the problem explicitly states that the tree doesn't have to be balanced. I'm just suggesting that will probably be the next problem your teacher asks you to solve. (And hopefully he'll teach you how to do so before asking you to do it.)